# share option in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, share

i wanna provide share option from my windows app to another apps in my windows phone, like android develpement. please any one tell, is it possible in windows phone. (using RT, not in silver Light) Thank You in advance.

For example: like the below image

[image]

I am using below code using "[How to use ShareLinkTask namespace in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924949/how-to-use-sharelinktask-namespace-in-windows-phone-8-1)" link.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager dtManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dtManager.DataRequested += dtManager_DataRequested;
}

private async void dtManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Code Samples";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";
    e.Request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps"));
}
// Click Button to share Web Link
private void btnShareLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

but it displays a progress bar with a message Preparing content to share and then it disappears, with no UI for sharing.
what should I do.please help me.

Comment: please see my updated post

Comment: Have you looked online, e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishasingh/archive/2013/01/16/sharing-data-from-a-windows-store-app-using-winrt-api.aspx